# SQL Server: check for value in a range between 2 columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to find values between a range from 2 different col.
Below is the structure of my table :

```
OBJECT      FIELD  LOW  HIGH   
----------------------------
S_IDOCMONI  ACTVT  01   03
```

I wanted to search for values 01, 02 and 03 between cols LOW and HIGH. Currently i have written a CASE statement only to check in col LOW :

```
select * 
into [abc] 
from
    (select 
         *,
         case
            when [OBJECT] = 'S_IDOCCTRL' and [FIELD] = 'ACTVT' and [LOW] in ('01') 
               then '1'
         end [Subgroup]
     from
         [user-master]) as x 
where 
    subgroup is not null
```

Could anyone help me where I can search for value 02 (as a range between cols. LOW and HIGH)

Comment: What results exactly are you looking for? Adding some expected results  will help us figure out exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)